# Is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ being the ring of all functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
with multiplication and addition defined as follows:

(*f*+*g*)(*x*) = *f*(*x*) + *g*(*x*)

(*fg*)(*x*) = *f*(*x*)g(*x*)

I know that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{X}$ is a ring when $\mathbb{X}$ is a finite set, but I'm not quite sure how the axioms would work with infinite sets.

Thank you

Comment: You can think of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ as the direct product $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{R}$, if that helps. But yes, it is a ring.

Comment: Is there a ring axiom that fails?

Comment: In fact, for any $Y$, $X^Y$ is a ring whenever $X$ is a ring.

Comment: Sum and multiplication of real numbers are reals numbers too, so...

Comment: @OpenBall ... Contrariwise, I would say $X^Y$ is a ring whenever $X$ is a ring.

Comment: @GEdgar I always forget which one is the domain and which one is the codomain in $X^Y$..

Comment: @LeonSot got it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it is a ring.

Since $(\mathbb R^{\mathbb R},+)$ is an abelian group (the inverse of a function $f$ is...$-f=[x\mapsto -f(x)]$). And the other axioms are verified too.

Answer (score 1):

More general if  $\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R})$ with $X\ne \emptyset $ is the set of all functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then, $\left(\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R}\right),+,\cdot)$ is an unitary and communtative ring.

Comment: Strange for you to switch notation from that used by the question